# Why Graph API throws an error while retrieving basic user's info?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having strange situation here. When I run code like this:

```
try{
    $response = $fb->sendRequest('GET', '/1317727711586522', array(
        'fields' => 'id,name,picture'
    ), $access_token);
}catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e){
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e){
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;}

$usersData=$response->getDecodedBody();
$usersName=$usersData['name'];
$usersId=$usersData['id'];
$usersPicture=$usersData['picture']['data']['url'];
```

Everything works fine and Graph returns no error at all. But when I'm listing user's facebook ids from my database, it returns an error: `Graph returned an error: Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api` . And here's my code for doing this:

```
  $queryForUsers="SELECT * FROM $tabela";
    $resultForUsers=$mysqli->query($queryForUsers);
    //var_dump($resultForUsers);
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => $apid,
        'app_secret' => $appSecret,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);
    $access_token=$apid.'|'.$appSecret;
    while($userRow=$resultForUsers->fetch_assoc()){

        try{
            $response = $fb->sendRequest('GET', '/'.$userRow['user_facebook_id'], array(
                'fields' => 'id,name,picture'
            ), $access_token);
        }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e){
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e){
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;}
}
```

Note two things please: All users that I have in my database have installed and approved my app, and I have their real `facebook ids`, and second thing: When i go hardcoding `ids` from database, one by one, it returns no errors. Please help me if you have encountered such error.

Comment: what do you mean with "real facebook ids"? you are not supposed to use the "real ids" anymore, only app scoped ones. "Unsupported get request" usually means that you are trying to do something you´re not supposed to - or you lack permissions to do so.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, ids that my app provides.

Comment: If it works once it is hardcoded and typed manually, then it means that the type of variable you are trying to pass through the query is not matching the variable type of variable the API is expecting from you.

Comment: Are the access tokens the same in all requests?